# evaluate, iterateNext and setAttribute for every result?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm using this code to find a `li` that contains Unicode and add color to it, the problem is that it only works on the first result...

```
var headings = document.evaluate("//li[contains(., '★')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
thisHeading.setAttribute('style', 'color: #f1c40f');
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` use `XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE`.

```js
var headings = document.evaluate("//li[contains(., '★')]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );

for ( var i=0 ; i < headings.snapshotLength; i++ ) {
    headings.snapshotItem(i).style.color = "#f1c40f";
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li>★</li>
     <li>★</li>
     <li>★</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over it to do it for all iterations

Like this

```
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
while (thisHeading) {
  thisHeading.setAttribute('style', 'color: #f1c40f');
  thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
}
```

Comment: (index):711 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The document has mutated since the result was returned.
    at https://www.example.com/:711:26
(anonymous) @ (index):711
Show 1 more frame